# setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds vs. android:drawableRight

Tags: android

What is the difference between setting a drawable via xml like

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right_normal"
```

and setting a drawable via code like

```
bt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.arrow_right_normal);
```

Because in the first case everything works like expected (Buttontext is center horizantal and the icon is in the middle of the right side).
And in the second case the icon is at the bottom/middle of the Button and the Text is at the top left side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`right` is the third parameter. The last one is bottom

```
bt.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.arrow_right_normal,0);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) the documentation

Answer (score 1):

```
Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
   getResources(),
   R.drawable.visibility_off,
   getTheme()
); 

textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,drawable,null);
```